# Nginx multiple hosts with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I have 2 apps in Ruby on Rails. + Passenger. They are at `/var/www/app1` and `/var/www/app2`. I want to use a prefix in the URL to determine which one I wanna hit.

So let's say `http://example.com/app1/users?order=id` goes to app1 and `http://example.com/app2/items` goes to app2.

How can I achieve this? I tried to solve it using proxy but did success.

UPDATE: Here is my tries. But I am not sure that I am doing it right.

```
location ~ ^/app1 {
    rewrite /app1(.*) /$1  break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9111;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
location ~ ^/app2 {
    rewrite /app2(.*) /$1  break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9112;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

server {
  listen 9112;
  listen [::]:9112;
  error_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log;
  # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
  passenger_enabled on;
  root /var/www/app2/public;
  rails_env development;
}

server {
  listen 9111;
  listen [::]:9111;
  error_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log;
  # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
  passenger_enabled on;
  root /var/www/app1/public;
  rails_env development;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your config for NGINX that you've tried?

Comment: @KeenanLawrence added a snippet. But I am not sure that I am doing it right.

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the expected result and what is actually happening?